# iptables wont let me connect to mysql from remote server

Tags: centos, mysql, iptables

I have 2 servers, DB_server (1.1.1.1) and app_server (2.2.2.2)

created a user on DB_server for app_server (with 2.2.2.2 as hostname)
But I am not able to connect from app_server to db_server.

When I shut down iptables on db_server, I am able to connect fine.
So that makes me think the issue is with iptables on db_server.

bind-address is 0.0.0.0 on db_server, which is working.

This is what I have done so far, from app_server, with iptables enabled on db_server:

```
# telnet 1.1.1.1 3306
Trying 1.1.1.1...
telnet: connect to address 1.1.1.1: No route to host
```

With iptables disabled on db_server:

```
# telnet 1.1.1.1 3306
Trying 1.1.1.1...
Connected to 1.1.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
R
```

So that means I am able to connect fine without iptables.

This is iptables -S on db_server

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10081 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10090:10100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I have been trying to make this work for a while now, came up with this to allow the connection from 2.2.2.2, but it is not working after iptables-save

```
-A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I am kind of lost, I feel like I am doing the correct things, but it is not working... Any pointers?

Comment: The order matters. Your rule for port 3306 is behind the reject rule.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.
And it also works... Are you able to give me an answer? I will accept it

Comment: No need to post the same answer again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your rule as below:

```
 -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10081 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10090:10100 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
 -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```